# Синоніми до „Якщо ..., то ...“

Tags: синоніми

Мене цікавить,які можна навести правильні синонімічні варіанти до такої зв'язки „Якщо <перелік умов>, то <висновки>“. Мені спадає на думку лише один варіант „Нехай ..., тоді ...“.
Колись мене переконували у тому, що варіант „Якщо ..., тоді ...“ безглуздий. Мовляв, правильним є „Нехай <перелік умов>. Тоді <висновки>“, тобто утворюються два речення (додав уточнення з огляду на першу відповідь).

Тому буду вдячним як за синоніми до „Якщо ..., то ...“, так і за пояснення, чому варіант „Якщо ..., тоді ...“ - невдалий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Відповідь на запитання слід розглядати в контексті складнопідрядних обставинних речень.

Стисло й зрозуміло викладено у посібнику [УКРАЇНСЬКА МОВА. ПІДГОТОВКА ДО ЗНО](http://www.subject.com.ua/ukrmova/zno/299.html)

> Підрядні обставинні речення поділяються на такі види: підрядні
>   ***місця***, ***часу***, ***ступеня і способу дії***, ***мети***, ***причини***, ***умовні***, ***допустові***, ***наслідкові***.

Зосередимось на умовних і допустових обставинних складнопідрядних, оскільки саме щодо цих у автора виникли певні труднощі.

> **Підрядними умовними** називаються речення, що вказують, за якої умови можливе те, про що йдеться в головному реченні, і відповідають
>   на питання ***`за якої умови?`***
>
> *Якби я турбувався лиш про себе, вже б онімів давно від самоти* (Д. Павличко). *Якщо на Василів вечір (14 січня) зірок на небі рясно —
>   чекайте ягідного літа* (3 календаря).
>
> З головним реченням підрядні умовні **поєднуються сполучниками**
>   ***`коли`***, ***`якщо`***, ***`якби`***, ***`як`*** та ін. Цим сполучникам **у головному реченні може відповідати сполучник**
>   ***`то`***:
>
> *Як виросту, збудую хату, над дахом колесо приб'ю...* (Д. Павличко).
>
> **Підрядними допустовими** називаються речення, які вказують на умови, незважаючи на які або всупереч яким відбувається дія, виражена в
>   головному реченні, і які відповідають на питання ***`незважаючи на що?`***
>
> *У полі ще лежав сніг, хоч весна брала своє.*
>
> З головним реченням підрядні допустові **поєднуються сполучниками**
>   ***`хоч`***, ***`хоча`***, ***`хай`***, ***`нехай`***, ***`дарма що`***, ***`незважаючи на те що`*** та ін.
>
> Якщо підрядне допустове речення стоїть перед головним, то **між
>   реченнями можуть вживатися протиставні сполучники** ***`а`***,
>   ***`але`***, ***`зате`***, ***`однак`***, ***`проте`***.
>
> *Де б я не був, а все ж думками лечу в Донеччину свою* (В. Сосюра).
>
> Окрім сполучників, підрядні допустові **поєднуються з головним
>   реченням сполучними словами** ***`скільки`***, ***`як`*** **з
>   підсилювальною часткою** ***`не`***.
>
> *Скільки на море не дивись, воно ніколи не набридне. Як вовка не годуй, він усе в ліс дивиться* (Народна творчість).

**Отже**, ***`якщо...то`*** можна замінити ***`коли..то`***,  ***`якби...то`***, ***`як...то`***, (підрядне речення повинно відповідати на запитання ***`за якої умови?`***).

***`Нехай`*** можна замінити на ***`хоч`***, ***`хоча`***, ***`хай`***, ***`нехай`***, ***`дарма що`***, ***`незважаючи на те що`*** та ін. (підрядне речення повинно відповідати на запитання ***`незважаючи на що?`***). Допустові підрядні зазвичай утворюються без вказівних слів.

Варіанти ***`нехай...тоді`***, ***`якщо...тоді`*** дійсно поза нормою, бо ***`тоді`*** є вказівним словом для обставинних підрядних часу.

> **Підрядними часу** називаються речення, що вказують на час дії в головному реченні і відповідають на питання ***`коли?`***
>   ***`відколи?`*** ***`як довго?`*** ***`з якого часу?`*** ***`до якого часу?`***
>
> *А мамина колискова звучить найніжнішою музикою і **тоді, коли** посрібляться наші скроні* (Н. Дмитровська). *І складаються
>   строфи-куплети, коли серце болить і плаче* (С. Пушик). *Не пробуй з
>   ковалем у кузні розмовлять, як молоток його з ковадлом у розмові* (М.
>   Рильський).
>
> З головним реченням підрядні часу **поєднуються за допомогою сполучних
>   слів і сполучників** ***`коли`***, ***`поки`***, ***`доки`***,
>   ***`ледве`***, ***`скоро`***, ***`щойно`***, *`як`*, ***`тільки`***, ***`як тільки`*** тощо.
>
> Для зв'язку підрядних речень із головним можуть також слугувати
>   с**ловосполучення, до складу яких входять сполучники підрядності**:
>   ***`після того як`***, ***`у той час як`***, ***`відтоді як`***, ***`з того часу як`***, ***`у той час коли`*** та ін.
>
> Найчастіше перша половина цих словосполучень входить до складу
>   головного речення, а друга — підрядного: *Бо пісня доти ще жива, допоки
>   хтось її співає* (Г. Чубач).

Наочно матеріал щодо усіх обставинних підрядних речень викладено в таблицях. [1](http://konspektu.at.ua/publ/9_klas/ukrajinska_mova/osnovni_vidi_skladnopidrjadnikh_rechen_rozriznennja_spoluchnikiv_i_spoluchnikh_sliv/49-1-0-1494), [2](http://zno.academia.in.ua/mod/book/view.php?id=1387&chapterid=204)

**UPD.** Як підказав [@Sasha](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/4/sasha), згідно із четвертим значенням  в СУМ [***`тоді`***](http://sum.in.ua/s/todi):

> 4. **Уживається в головному реченні у знач. співвідносного слова до сполучників** `коли`**,** `як`**,** `якби` **або** `без сполучника` **в *підрядному умови*.** *Тоді сироті неділя, як сорочка
>      біла* (Номис, 1864, № 700); *Якби мої думи німії та піснею стали без
>      слова, вони б тоді більше сказали, ніж вся моя довга розмова* (Леся
>      Українка, I, 1951, 198); *Коли шумує в серці кров І прагне радісної
>      муки, — Який широкий світ тоді — Ніяким не окинуть оком* (Максим
>      Рильський, II, 1960, 284); *Мати тоді сита, коли діти не голодні*
>      (Костянтин Гордієнко, II, 1959, 19); — *Гляди, Маковею, вдруге
>      розгубишся: тоді амінь тобі!* (Олесь Гончар, III, 1959, 59).

Comment: Ваша відповідь бездоганна. Знайдені вами синоніми справді підходять до розмовного, художнього чи публіцистичного стилю. Але, от думаю, чи гарно вони виглядатимуть у науковому стилі, а саме у математичній статті?

Comment: @АндрійБандура, перепрошую, та в запитанні не було зазначено контекст) Щодо математичної статті не підкажу, бо не спеціаліст у цій галузі.

Comment: Все ж таки, один ваш варіант навіть у математичному тексті підійде - „Коли ..., то ...“

Comment: @АндрійБандура, чудово, що відповідь задовільнила автора запитання. Одне застереження: варіанти не мої, а з посібника)

Comment: @АндрійБандура, як щодо «Припуст{и,і}мо <…>. Тоді <…>.» (на додаток до вже названого Вами «Нехай <…>. Тоді <…>.»; до речі, «тоді» ще можна замінити на «в такому разі», «за таких умов»)? До речі, чому «тоді» є вказівним *лише* для обставинних підрядних часу — он в СУМ-11 третє значення: «у такому разі, за таких обставин, умов» (хіба це автоматично не означає, що його можна використовувати замість «в такому разі», «за таких умов»?).

Comment: @Sasha, я ж не написала *лише*:), але так само й значення в СУМ "3. У такому разі, за таких обставин, умов." не означає "автоматично", що можна використовувати як вказівне слово. У жодному із наведених прикладів до цього 3-го значення *тоді* не вжито як вказівне слово для умовних обставникових підрядних. На захист Вашого коментаря, мабуть, краще підходить  4-те значення в СУМ. Та й то із застереженням, бо зазначається, що в обстанникових умови *тоді* вживається як співвідносне слово або *без сполучника* у підрядному реченні, або до сполучників *коли*, *як*, *якби*, але не *нехай* і не *якщо*.

Comment: @Sasha, додала апдейт до відповіді. Дякую за коментар.